# ADFS 2.0 - using claim rules to find out when password expires

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs

I need ADFS 2.0 to tell my relying party application when current user's password will expire. Basically, I need to extract all the data from AD, using ADFS claim rules, to repeat logic of this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2010/08/09/9970198.aspx

I can access user-level AD attribute "Pwd-Last-Set" without problems (other than changed value caching for around 20 minutes), but:

1. I can not access domain-level attributes (like Max-Pwd-Age) from claim rules. How can I do that?
2. I can not find appropriate attributes for some of the data, like DomainMode.

May be there is some ready solution to this problem, which my googling skills where too weak to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access AD attributes that pertain to the logged-in user.

For this kind of thing, I would suggest writing a [custom attribute store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895358.aspx) which returns the info. you require.